# force connection using USB adapter

Tags: ubuntu, usb, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I am new to Linux, so even though this is probably a simple problem it remains unsolved after more then 3 hours of googling.

I am run running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire 5520G.  The laptop has a wireless adapter, but since I wanted better range I got an Edimax EW-7711USN USB adapter.  Now,  when running ifconfig, I am able to see both adapters.  The laptop native adapter is listed as **wlan0** and the usb adapter is listed as **wlan1**.

But listing available networks from the wireless network applet, all the connections are listed under wlan0.  The USB adapter is consistently listed as disconnected.  This is what I have been trying to do so far:

1. `ifconfig wlan0 down`  -  I got disconnected from the net but still was not able to get the USB to connect.
2. Used the wireless connection dialog to connect to a hidden network with the USB adapter - I was able to connect to the network but with no Internet access.
3. Disabled wireless using the laptop function button - both wireless adapters were  disabled.

Can anyone suggest a way to connect to to the wireless network using the USB adapter rather then the built-in adapter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should also work for Ubuntu:

http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_Guide#Wireless_Quickstart_For_the_Live_Environment_.28If_you_need_wireless_connectivity_during_the_installation_process.29

Comment: the link points to limbo :-(

Comment: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Wireless_Quickstart_For_the_Live_Environment_.28If_you_need_wireless_connectivity_during_the_installation_process.29

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a different network manager like Wicd? As far as I know, this one allows you to say which adapter you want to use in its preferences.